# Should a site that has been hit by Google Penguin penalties update content or create new?

Tags: seo

Some time back we created tutorials on a test tool [Quality Center](http://www.guru99.com/quality-center-tutorials.html) which now needs upgrading.
Currently the tool has been renamed to **HP ALM**.

Our dilemma is whether we should create new pages for the new tutorials or update the existing tutorials itself? To add to our pain, most of the end users still refer the new **ALM** with its old name **Quality Center**. Also we here hit by Penguin 2.1 and since then have been very precautions from SEO standpoint.

Answer (score 2):

I would add HP ALM and Application Lifecycle Management to the meta keywords on the actual Site.

Further I´d add a Banner, which says that the QC got renamed into -> ALM and that they can find the new tutorials under this **link.**

Then I´d add a new Site for the new Tutorials,(but still add Quality Center, QC etc. to the meta keywords)  with a Banner on it, which says if they are looking for tutorials for older versions they can be found **here**

I think that solves all your problems.

1. New tutorials can be found under old Name
2. Old tutorials can be found under new Name
3. Search Engines will index the New Page with a Backlink to the Site with the older Tutorials
4. Search Engines will index the Old Page with a Backlink to the site with the new Tutorials

---

And don´t forget to tell Google and Bing to Re-Index the site, else it takes like 4-5 Months